# Took a computer out of a domain that does not exist anymore - User's documents gone

Tags: active-directory, windows-7, user-profile

We have long ago switched off our Windows Domain.
A user came in with his laptop, that was still a member of it.
I think the Desktop and files were synced with the fileserver,
but that doesn't exist anymore either.
So Windows saved the files locally.
I copied the user's local directory (`C:\users\`) and copied it to a safe location(s),
which succeeded without errors (so I didn't completely check if everything was there).
I assumed that would get me all the user's files.

Then I took the computer out of the domain.

Now I noticed "My Documents" seems to be Empty, which would be very bad.
The Desktop came over, the Documents didn't.
I did the copy multiple times without errors.

I guess windows simply removed them when the computer was taken out of the domain, and didn't copy them because (maybe) I copied them as the local Administrator.

Is there some place on the disk I could perhaps find these files?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if the domain had been using folder redirection to move "my documents" to a network share and synced to the laptop using offline files, then they are probably in the Client Side Cache. this post on [superuser.com](https://superuser.com/questions/307201/extract-files-from-csc-offline-files-folder) gives instructions on how to use [microsoft's csccmd.exe tool](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/884739) to recover those files.

Comment: Thx man!! Will try this at once.